# How to set up an enum to allow multiple enums in a query? GraphQL Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

I have an enum, `item_status.rb` defined in `app/graphql/graph/enums` that looks something like this:

```
Graph::Enums::ItemStatus = GraphQL::EnumType.define do
 name "ItemStatus"
 description "lorem ipsum"
 
 value "GOOD", "item is good", value: "good"
 value "NORMAL", "item is normal", value: "normal"
 value "BAD", "item is bad", value: "bad"

end
```

It's defined in my `schema.graphql` like this:

```
enum ItemStatus {
 GOOD
 NORMAL
 BAD
}
```

I want to send a query from my front-end that contains multiple values for ItemStatus, for example in my queryVariables I'd send `status: ["GOOD", "NORMAL"]` and I want to receive all items with either of those statuses back. How do I modify my schema to accept an array of values as well as a single value?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the argument in your query just be an array of strings?

```
field :your_field, YourType do
  argument :status, [String], required: true
end
```

```
def your_field(status:)
  Mymodel.where(status: status)
end
```

I might be missing something about what you are trying to do though.

Comment: what will be the front-end query for this

Answer (score 1):

I prefer you need to send the array of enum like [GOOD,NORMAL] for query variable

Define your graphql field like this:

```
field :Items, ReturnType do
  argument :statuses, [Graph::Enums::ItemStatus], required: true
end

def Items(statuses:)
  Item.where(status: statuses)
end
```